# Impossible to get an ad to display in an AdView

Tags: java, android, ads

I want to add an `AdView` to my application but I can succeed in recovering a test ad. The `AdView` is correctly shown but it only represents a white rectangle.

In the Log cat, my request for an ad gives the following lines :
"Starting ad request (info),"
"There was a problem getting an ad response. Error code 0 (warning)",
"Failed to load ad : 0 (warning).".

The code I use is exactly the one found in the Google tutorial. The Id used to declare my test device is the one displayed in the log cat, as explained in this tutorial and the result is not better if I try to get a non test ad.

What could prevent me from succeding in getting a test ad?

The code :

```
        view=(AdView)myView.findViewById(R.id.myAdView);
    request=new AdRequest.Builder()
        .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
        .addTestDevice("my test code")
        .build();
    view.loadAd(request);
```

In the Manifest file :

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

    <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize">
    </activity>
```

Comment: please describe you problem with source code so people can understand more and also add log cat with warning and error.

Comment: The code I use is cut/pasted from the tutorial but, nevertheless, I have added it in the text of my question.

Comment: hi, VD63 use this method to implement AdMob using Google Play Services by this link : https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/android/quick-start

Comment: With this link and a little more perspiration, I have finally succeeded in having my test ad displayed. Thanks!